# Relation between projective equivalence and linear equivalence of divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, divisors-algebraic-geometry

For the whole question I'll be working in $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ and assume that everything is smooth.

We say that two sets $U,V\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ are projectively equivalent if there exists an element $A\in PGL(n)$ such that $A\cdot U=V$.

With these concepts I think it's reasonable to say (define) that two Weyl divisors $D,D'$ are projectively equivalent if there is some automorphism $A$ such that $A\cdot D=D'$, where we define a linear action of $PGL(n)$ in the divisors in each summand, i.e., if $D=\sum a_iU_i$, then $A\cdot D :=\sum a_i (A\cdot U_i)$.

First of all I'd like to know if this makes sense, since I can't find this definition anywhere. In case it does, I'd like to know how is being projectively equivalent related to the divisors being linearly equivalent.

The question can be translated to showing that for any given divisor $D$ there exists and automorphism $A$ such that $(1-A)\cdot D$ is principal.

The motivation for this question is that all hyperplanes in $\mathbb{P}^n$ are linearly equivalent and projectively equivalent under the previous definition, yet both facts seem to be unrelated at a first glance.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but one confusing thing is that halfway through the question "projectively equivalent" seems to turn into "algebraically equivalent" (which is a different equivalence relation).

Comment: Hi, @Nefertiti, thanks for your comment. Could you be more specific? By reading the definition of algebraic equivalence in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adequate_equivalence_relation#Examples_of_equivalence_relations I don't see how it relates to my post.

Comment: My point is that you wrote the words "algebraically equivalent" twice in your question for no clear reason. If you are asking about projective equivalence, you should use the words "projectively equivalent".

Comment: Oh snap! my bad! @Nefertiti, thanks. I've edited the OP.

Comment: The union of two lines in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is linearly equivalent to a smooth conic, but obviously not projectively equivalent. By the way, your definition of projective equivalence seem to work only for $\mathbb{P}^n$. How would you extend it to arbitrary varieties ?

Comment: Another problem with your projective equivalence is that it doesn't behave well with respect of the sum of divisor : if $H,H'$ are two distinct hyperplanes, then $H\sim H'$ but $H+H'\not\sim 2 H$.

Comment: @Roland Your last claim made me realize we actually don't have a well defined additive structure in $PGL(n)$ (I think), so one of my paragraphs in the OP is wrong. In any case, how did you see that $H+H'\not\sim 2H$?

I think this could be extended simply by considering the automorphism group of any variety at hand.

Comment: Well it is just with you definition $A.(2H)=2(A.H)$ so you cannot separate the two $H$ anymore. Or even if you think geometrically $2H$ should be a double hyperplane whereas $H+H'$ are the union of two distincts hyperplane. You cannot find an automorphism that send one to the other. You should probably change your definition to say that $D\sim D'$ if there exists decomposition $D=D_1+...+D_r$, $D'=D'_1+...D'_r$ and automorphism $A_1,...,A_r$ such that $A_i D_i=D'_i$.

Comment: The problem for arbitrary varieties is that the automorphism group may be really small (finite or even trivial). So the notion is not really interesting.

Comment: @Roland I see, all your points are really helpful, thanks. Regarding the generalization you mention, which actually makes the action compatible with the group structure of the divisors, is it closer to being related with linear equivalence?

Comment: The thing is, quadrics will always be different from the sum of two lines. On arbitrary varieties, things will get even worse because of the size of the automorphism group. But it may also happen that two "automorphically equivalent" divisor are not linearly equivalent : take two different points in an elliptic curve.

Comment: @Roland I think this pretty much settles the matter. Could you summarize this discussion in an answer so it doesn't remain as an unanswered post? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here is a summary of my comments on this "projective equivalence".

I see several problems for this notion to be interesting :

- It is not compatible with the sum of divisors, though you can easily change the definition to have a better behaviour.
- On an arbitrary variety, you need to replace $PGL$ by the automorphism group, and this group can be very small, finite or even trivial. In that case, this notion is not really interesting.
- An irreducible divisor will only be equivalent to an isomorphic subset. This is very restrictive. In particular, a conic will not be equivalent to the union of two lines. But also two cubics can't be equivalent if they are not isomorphic.

Now for the comparison question : this equivalence is not finer nor coarser than the linear equivalence.

- As noted before, a conic and the union of two lines in $\mathbb{P}^2$ are linearly equivalent but they are not "projectively equivalent".
- On an elliptic curve, two distinct points are "automorphically equivalent" but not linearly equivalent.

Comment: this puts the nail in the coffin :)